# File not found error Ray installation Windows

Tags: python, visual-c++, multiprocessing, file-not-found, ray

I am trying to use Ray on Windows and have followed the [documentation](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/installation.html#windows-dependencies), but am unable to initialize Ray even though the latest [Visual C++ runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) is installed.

Whenever I run

```
import ray
ray.init()
```

I get the following error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\ray\worker.py", line 694, in init
    _global_node = ray.node.Node(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\ray\node.py", line 198, in __init__
    self.start_head_processes()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\ray\node.py", line 800, in start_head_processes
    self.start_redis()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\ray\node.py", line 571, in start_redis
    self.get_resource_spec(),
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\ray\node.py", line 287, in get_resource_spec
    self._resource_spec = ResourceSpec(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\ray\resource_spec.py", line 167, in resolve
    num_gpus = _autodetect_num_gpus()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\ray\resource_spec.py", line 278, in _autodetect_num_gpus
    lines = subprocess.check_output(cmdargs).splitlines()[1:]
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have tried installing both [x86: vc_redist.x86.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x86.exe) and [x64: vc_redist.x64.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe), but no dice. I have even reinstalled Visual Studio 2019 in hopes that it would fix something.

**How can I fix this error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `C:\Windows\System32\wbem` in your PATH env var. `_autodetect_num_gpus`  is failing to run wmic.exe which is in that folder.